# Retraction and direct limit

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, $M_0 \subseteq M_i \subseteq M_{i+1} \subseteq \dots $ is an increasing chain of $A-$modules and $M=\varinjlim M_i$. Assume for every $i$ there is a retraction $s_i:M_i \rightarrow M_0$ (may not compatible with the increasing chain), will there always exist a retraction $s:M \rightarrow M_0$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, not necessarily.  For instance, let $A=\mathbb{Z}$.  Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is not projective as an $A$-module, there is some short exact sequence $$0\to K\to M\stackrel{p}{\to}\mathbb{Q}\to 0$$ that does not split (explicitly, you could take $M$ to be any free module with a surjection to $\mathbb{Q}$).  Now let $M_i=p^{-1}(\frac{1}{i!}\mathbb{Z})\subset M$.  Then for each $i$, our short exact sequence restricts to a short exact sequence $$0\to K\to M_i\to \frac{1}{i!}\mathbb{Z}\to 0$$ which splits since $\frac{1}{i!}\mathbb{Z}$ is free.  This means that the inclusion $K\to M_i$ has a retraction for all $i$, but the colimit $K\to M$ does not.

More generally, you can get a similar example from any non-projective module that is the union of an ascending sequence of projective submodules.

Answer (score 4):

If there was a retraction $s:M\rightarrow M_0$, composition with the canonical morphisms $\nu_i: M_i \rightarrow M$ gives a system of retractions $s_i:M_i \rightarrow M_0$ that is compatible with the direct system in the sense that $s_{i+1}\iota_i=s_i,$ where $\iota_i: M_i \rightarrow M_{i+1}$ are the inclusions of the direct system. Thus, to disprove the claim it is enough to find a direct system that allows for retractions while does not allow for a system of compatible retractions.

Let us try to cook up some example of this where $M_i$ is the free Abelian group of rank $2$ for all $i >0$, and $M_0=\mathbb{Z}$. By choosing coordinates on $M_i$'s suitably, we may assume that the inlusions $M_0 \subseteq M_i$ coming from the direct system are of the form $$\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}: \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z},\;\; k \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ k\end{pmatrix}.$$

Then a retraction for any $M_i \rightarrow M_0$ is necessarily of the form $$\begin{pmatrix}k_i & 1\end{pmatrix}: \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z},$$
the inclusions $\iota_i: M_i \rightarrow M_{i+1}$ are necessarily of the form 
$$\begin{pmatrix}m_i & 0 \\ n_i &  1\end{pmatrix}:\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$$
(this form is forced upon us by the condition
$A \cdot\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$), and
we can also easily check that such a map is injective whenever $m_i \neq 0$.

So far, the situation was completely general, i.e. we did not make any real choices (we just considered suitably chosen coordinates). Let us now set $m_i=n_i=3$ for all $i>0$, i.e. consider a system where all the maps $\iota_i$ are, with the coordinate choice we made, of the form 
$$\begin{pmatrix}3 & 0 \\ 3 &  1\end{pmatrix}:\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}, \;\; \begin{pmatrix}a \\ b\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}3a\\ 3a +b\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then to have a compatible system of retractions $$M_i \rightarrow M_0$$ is to have $k_i$ satisfying 
$$k_{i}=3k_{i+1}+3,\; \text{  i.e.  }\;k_{i+1}=\frac{k_i}{3}-1$$

Now we can readily check that such collection of $k_i's$ cannot exist: The last recurrence relation allows for explicit form
$$k_{i+1}=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^i(k_1+\frac{3}{2})-\frac{3}{2},$$
and one can easily check that regardless of $k_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$, $k_{i+1}$ is not an integer for sufficiently large $i$.

Altogether, such system does not allow for a compatible system of retractions, hence there is no retraction to $M_0$ from the direct limit.

Comment: I don’t think you mean $M_0=0$?

Comment: @Jeremy Rickard : thank you, fixed.

Comment: Hah, this is essentially the example I first came up with, before I realized you could get a simpler (if less explicit) description by just talking about projectivity of modules.  To connect this answer with mine, you are explicitly constructing a non-split extension $0\to\mathbb{Z}\to M\stackrel{p}\to\mathbb{Z}[1/3]\to 0$ and then taking $M_i=p^{-1}(\frac{1}{3^i}\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes, you are right. I realized that when I saw your post afterwards.

Comment: @EricWofsey Interestingly enough, though, I wasn't able to make the argument stick for $m_i=n_i=2$, since then the associated recurrence relation allows for a stable $\mathbb{Z}$-solution $k_i=-2$. So I don't think that the examples are completely the same, since, if I am not mistaken, your above example should work regardless of a chosen prime $p$.

Comment: I haven't worked through the details, but I believe that your extension is the one corresponding to the $3$-adic number $-\frac{3}{2}$ when you identify $\mathrm{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}[1/3],\mathbb{Z})$ with $\mathbb{Z}_3/\mathbb{Z}$ in the natural way.  The fact that it doesn't work for $2$ is because $-\frac{2}{1}$ is $0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2/\mathbb{Z}$, so the extension splits.  But you could get a different example for $2$ by tweaking the numbers; for instance, you could take $m_i=n_i=4$ and would get a non-split extension $0\to\mathbb{Z}\to M\to \mathbb{Z}[1/2]\to 0$.